# Tcp Server Using Wcf Service

Tags: wcf, gps, tcplistener

I am an experienced C# developer, but I have not developed a TCP server application so far. Now I have to develop a highly scalable and high performance server that can handle at least 5-10 thousand concurrent connections: getting -raw byte- data via GPRS from GPS devices.

A common communication process should look like this:

GPS device initiates a connection to my server
my server answers if I want to get data
device send GPS data
my server sends report to the device about getting it (sg like checksum)
getting new data from GPS, reportm and this happens again and again
later GPS DEVICE closes the connection
So, in my server I need

trace connected/active clients
to close any client from server side
catch the event, when a device closes the connection
get byte data
send data to clients
I started to read about this topic over the internet, but it seems to be a nightmare for me. There are a lot of ways, but I could not find out which is the best.

Async socket methods seems the best for me, but writing code in this async style is terrible and not easy to debug.

So my quetsion is: which do you think the best way to implement a high performance TCP server in C#? Do you know any good open source component to do this? (I tried several ones, but I could not find a good one.)

Thanks in advance, any expert answers would be appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

Two suggested ideas you can use.

1. WCF TCP (Duplex?) - Here you can have an async pattern, where both the client and the server can call each other. Defintely needs some plumbing involved, but there is lots of documentation out there.
2. RESTFUL - I think this may be the better option for you. This is VERY easy to make async, and because of REST's stateless nature there is much less overhead. FYI, you can use TCP for this, although HTTP would probably be the better choice.